# Execution order with threads and PyGTK on Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, pygtk

I'm having issues with threads and PyGTK on Windows.  According the the [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq21.003.htp) (and my own experimentation), the only way to reliably update the GUI from a child thread is to use the `gobject.idle_add` function.  However, it can't be guaranteed when this function will be called.  How can I guarantee that the line following the `gobject.idle_add` gets called after the function it points to?

Very simple and contrived example:

```
import gtk
import gobject
from threading import Thread

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.button = gtk.Button("Click")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.onButtonClicked)
        self.textEntry = gtk.Entry()
        self.content = gtk.HBox()
        self.content.pack_start(self.button)
        self.content.pack_start(self.textEntry)
        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.quit)
        self.window.add(self.content)
        self.window.show_all()

    def onButtonClicked(self, button):
        Thread(target=self.startThread).start()

    def startThread(self):
        #I want these next 2 lines to run in order
        gobject.idle_add(self.updateText)
        print self.textEntry.get_text()

    def updateText(self):
        self.textEntry.set_text("Hello!")

    def quit(self, widget):
        gtk.main_quit()
```

gobject.threads_init()
x = Gui()
gtk.main()

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to update or access your GUI from a thread.  You're just asking for trouble.  For example, the fact that "`get_text`" works *at all* in a thread is almost an accident.  You might be able to rely on it in GTK - although I'm not even sure about that - but you won't be able to do so in other GUI toolkits.

If you have things that really need doing in threads, you should get the data you need from the GUI *before* launching the thread, and then update the GUI from the thread by using `idle_add`, like this:

```
import time
import gtk
import gobject
from threading import Thread

w = gtk.Window()
h = gtk.HBox()
v = gtk.VBox()
addend1 = gtk.Entry()
h.add(addend1)
h.add(gtk.Label(" + "))
addend2 = gtk.Entry()
h.add(addend2)
h.add(gtk.Label(" = "))
summation = gtk.Entry()
summation.set_text("?")
summation.set_editable(False)
h.add(summation)
v.add(h)
progress = gtk.ProgressBar()
v.add(progress)
b = gtk.Button("Do It")
v.add(b)
w.add(v)
status = gtk.Statusbar()
v.add(status)
w.show_all()

def hardWork(a1, a2):
    messages = ["Doing the hard work to add %s to %s..." % (a1, a2),
                "Oof, I'm working so hard...",
                "Almost done..."]
    for index, message in enumerate(messages):
        fraction = index / float(len(messages))
        gobject.idle_add(progress.set_fraction, fraction)
        gobject.idle_add(status.push, 4321, message)
        time.sleep(1)
    result = a1 + a2
    gobject.idle_add(summation.set_text, str(result))
    gobject.idle_add(status.push, 4321, "Done!")
    gobject.idle_add(progress.set_fraction, 1.0)


def addthem(*ignored):
    a1 = int(addend1.get_text())
    a2 = int(addend2.get_text())
    Thread(target=lambda : hardWork(a1, a2)).start()

b.connect("clicked", addthem)
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
gtk.main()
```

If you really, absolutely need to read data from the GUI in the middle of a thread (this is a really bad idea, don't do it - you can get into really surprising deadlocks, especially when the program is shutting down) there is a utility in Twisted, [blockingCallFromThread](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.html#blockingCallFromThread), which will do the hard work for you.  You can use it like this:

```
from twisted.internet.gtk2reactor import install
install()
from twisted.internet import reactor

from twisted.internet.threads import blockingCallFromThread
from threading import Thread

import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
v = gtk.VBox()
e = gtk.Entry()
b = gtk.Button("Get Text")

v.add(e)
v.add(b)
w.add(v)

def inThread():
    print 'Getting value'
    textValue = blockingCallFromThread(reactor, e.get_text)
    print 'Got it!', repr(textValue)

def kickOffThread(*ignored):
    Thread(target=inThread).start()

b.connect("clicked", kickOffThread)
w.show_all()

reactor.run()
```

If you want to see how the magic works, you can always [read the source](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/internet/threads.py#L89).

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the two functions into another function and call idle_add on this function:

```
def update_and_print(self):
        self.updateText()
        print self.textEntry.get_text()

def startThread(self):
        gobject.idle_add(self.update_and_print)
```

Comment: The problem is that in my actual code, I'm not always running the same line after calling the function.  Depending on the context, I may call something else after the function call.

Comment: Can't you check for this particular condition inside the update_and_print callback?

Comment: Well, also the work after the GUI update is CPU intensive, which would block the main GUI loop, and I'm not going to spawn a new thread to do the work that the initial thread was created for.